# Pairing 2 lists Scheme

Tags: scheme, r5rs

SCHEME/Racket/R5RS

Attempting to make a recursive procedure that pairs 2 lists of the same size. Just cant get the recursive call right.
This is what I have and I am stuck.

```
(define (pairs list1 list2)
  (if (or (null? list1) (null? list2))
      '()
        (cons (car list1) (car list2))
        ))
```

Test Case:
(pairs '(1 2 3) '(a b c)) 
Desired Output: ((1 . a) (2 . b) (3 . c))
Current Output: (1 . a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to `cons` the current result to the recursive call of the procedure, and that's it!

```
(define (pairs list1 list2)
  (if (or (null? list1) (null? list2))
      '()
      (cons (cons (car list1) (car list2))
            (pairs (cdr list1) (cdr list2)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be an acceptable solution as well?

```
(define pairs
      (lambda (x y)
        (map cons x y)))
```